# Eclipse GWT Maven

Tags: eclipse, web-applications, gwt, maven, dependencies

I am working with Eclipse and the GWT Plugin to develop a web Interface for my application.
We are using maven with pom to resolve dependencies in the project.

At compile time I am having no trouble and everything runs smoothly.

The problem starts when I try to run the app on the development server that comes with the gwt plugin. It does not seem to resolve the pom.xml and dependencies at runtime.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/faq.html#gwt_with_maven ?